# I landed on an attack page - what to do?

Tags: gmail, security

I clicked a link in a gmail message, and arrived at a page that looks like a news site. I clicked a similar link in the next gmail message, and arrived at a page that warns that this is an "attack page": https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-mMfXyy8lylSkZTY2hNZG8zNUk

Now, I am sure that the first link I clicked was sent to me from the same email address, so I already entered an 'attack page'. How can I check if my computer has been attacked?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also, do you use any antivirus software?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04, with no anti-virus. But the "attack-page" speaks not only about viruses but all sorts of other attacks...

Comment: What was the first link you clicked?

Comment: http: // elbruk.pl / components / com_ag_google_analytics2 / google.html     (inserted spaces to prevent accidental clicking)

Comment: That pages doesn't appear to be on the same domain as Google Docs, so how is it related to Google Docs?

Comment: Of course it's not related to Google - it's an attack page...

Comment: You said that the first link you clicked was "from the same source", even though it's not on the same domain as the other link. I don't really understand what you're saying:  How can the links be from the same source when they are on two completely different websites?

Comment: I got the emails from the same person, one after the other. That person told me that his computer was hijacked. So, I conclude that the same evil source sent the two emails.

Comment: haven't really read it nor am i familiar with this but i suggest you change your password if you think it makes sense to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an anti-virus that didn't flag anything, chances are you are fine. Refresh the virus definitions and run a "full" scan to make sure.

If you are running an Linux OS like Ubuntu, I'd bet a month's salary that, unless you gave an attack site personal information, nothing happened and you can safely forget it happened.

Worse case is that the link in the email contained a code that let the attack site know that your email address is valid. Just be careful about [phishing attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) in the future. I personally never click a link in an email from a financial institution, I type the address in manually--for example if paypal tells me I owe them money, i type in www.paypal.com instead of clicking on a link because there are some awfully good phishing emails.